# Change in electric-energy for collection of dipoles?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, statistical-mechanics

You have a dipole interacting with a static electric field. The potential energy of this interaction is given by $U=-\bf{p}(\bf{E})\cdot\bf{E}$. Now suppose you change the $\bf{E}$-field a little, by $\delta\bf{E}$. The change in energy of this dipole is then

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{E}U\cdot\delta\bf{E}&=\nabla_E(-\bf{p}(\bf{E})\cdot\bf{E})\cdot\delta\bf{E}\\
&=-\left[(\bf{p}\cdot\nabla_E)\bf{E}+(\bf{E}\cdot\nabla_E)\bf{p}+\bf{p}\times(\nabla_E\times E)+E\times(\nabla_E\times\bf{p})\right]\cdot\delta \bf{E}\\
&=-\left[\bf{p}+(\bf{E}\cdot\nabla_E)\bf{p}+\bf{E}\times(\nabla_E\times p)\right]\cdot\delta\bf{E}
\end{align}$$

I think the cross-product term can be crossed out by some argument, but I'm not totally sure. Anyway, if we sum this $\delta U$ over a collection of isotropically-oriented dipoles, I know the answer is supposed to be

$$\delta U_{\text{tot}}=-\bf{P}\cdot\delta \bf{E}$$

where $\bf{P}$ is the total polarization of the collection of dipoles (note: it's not the polarization-density). How do I prove this?

Comment: Goodness. Why not just work in terms of components and get rid of all the vector-calculus confusion?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Because vector calculus identities for 3D are easy to remember and look up. I'll try breaking it down into components and see if that helps.

Comment: Seriously, it's not worth it - the vector gradient $\nabla_\mathbf{E}\mathbf p$ is just much too much trouble. It's either trivial, if your (linear) material is isotropic, or it's the linear polarizability tensor $\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial E_j}= \alpha_{ij}$ of the dipole if it's not, and in the latter case you want the explicit tensor out in the open or you'll just make it harder for yourself. (That's even *more* true if your material is not linear.)

Comment: My hope was that it would go away upon averaging over the isotropic collection of dipoles.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, that's still going to be easier via explicit component notation.